# jQuery Mobile - elements active on light touch when scrolling

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm sure that you have seen this kind of problem. I have a page with a list of elements and i have created a class `active` when i click on them, but when i scroll the page they trigger it (after a light touch) and became "active". I don't know how to do, this is the code which i use now, but it is no perfect because don't work at 100%

```
$("ul li").bind("vmousedown",function(){
   $(this).addClass("active");
}).bind("vmouseup vmouseout scrollstart scrollstop", function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
});
```

Do you have others solutions for this problem?

Comment: `scrollstart` and `scrollstop` should be bound to `$(window)` not `$("element")`. Also change `$(this).removeClass("active");` to this `$(".active").removeClass("active");`

Comment: @Omar i tried your changes but are working not well as my code. I only change the `$(this)` with `$(".active")`.

Comment: add more details, or create a js fiddle.

Comment: @Omar [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KgfQ4/1/) is an example, but you can see the issue on a mobile device. In mobile when i touch the screen for scrolling the element get the class active if touched (of course). I want that the element is active only on a "full click" but seems that the `vmousedown` is not perfect for this

Comment: maybe this one is close to what you need http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ER2qM/ test it on mobile

Comment: @Omar interesting solution, i'll let you know after trying it..thanks for your contribute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42509/discussion-between-omar-and-rajin)